# How can use a Notification Listener with a CupertinoPicker widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get the value of my CupertinoPicker’s index only when it settles. The documentation states “To get the value only when the scrolling settles, use a NotificationListener, listen for `ScrollEndNotification` and read its FixedExtentMetrics.”

How does this actually work? For the moment I just tried to wrap my CupertinoPicker widget in a `NotificationListener` and tried to implement the `onNotification` callback but this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you were almost there. This should do the trick.

More info in this article: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                onNotification: (scrollNotification){
                  if (scrollNotification is ScrollEndNotification) {

                    //Will only update when user has stopped scrolling in picker.
                    print(_pickerValue);

                    return true;
                  } else {
                    return false;
                  }
                },
                child: CupertinoPicker(
                  itemExtent: 30,
                  scrollController: scrollController,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('First'),
                    Text('Second'),
                    Text('Third'),
                  ],
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (int value) {
                    setState(() {
                      //Will update every time picker value changes.
                      _pickerValue = scrollController.selectedItem;

                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: @ Eric Duffett, u really saved my day... I tried so many options to achieve this. Finally, I was trying by put on a timer to judge if scrolling has stopped or not by comparing changed values. But this is a much better solution .....